# Are Launchpad bugs in a way moderated?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

Is Launchpad (in general) moderated?

- brainstorm is
- ask ubuntu is
- ubuntu answers is

what about ubuntu bugs?

Comment: It would help if you can give an example.  To judge from your comments below about "sack the maintainer" you do have one in mind.

Answer (score 8):

**[Bug 45419](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/45419) asks for a way for users to report posts/comments/content as spam or abuse**.  At the moment there is no formal mechanism but you can as in `#launchpad` or [file a support question against Launchpad itself](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad).

Comment: AFAICT that's still the case. I have some minimal permissions on Inkscape Answers, it appears, but no ability to report blatant spam -- "bitcoin support dial 1-800-this-spam" or whatever -- nor any ability to flag the new user that posted that 15 times ... infuriating. It's way too much friction to write a bug report against Launchpad to fix such spam. AFAICT in 2017 there is still no other way to get it fixed. Makes Launchpad look like an unmaintained mess.

Answer (score 7):

For new bug reports on Launchpad the terminology is ***triaging***, rather than ***moderating***.

Triaging gives bugs a relative importance and priority, in addition to categorising them against the correct part of Ubuntu.  You can read more about the triaging facilities at:

- [dev.launchpad.net/BugTriage](https://dev.launchpad.net/BugTriage)

Occasionally (but very rarely) patent nonsense gets filed in Launchpad, in which case it is marked "Invalid"—being impossible to process further.  Marketing spam added as comments to existing bug reports may also be deleted.

Does that answer your query?  Is there any area that you're still interested in, or which you'd like expanding with more detail?

Answer (score 3):

Is it moderated? Well depends upon what you mean by "Moderated". Is it customizable in regards to team creation and management? Yes, you can moderate your team(s) and/or project(s) on Launchpad. Quite easily too once you get the hang of it. But in general usage, difficult to say. Anyone can go look at the site and browse but to do anything you do actually have to register and confirm your account. From there it's pretty much "Have at it..." at least to me.

Comment: What about abusive,"inflammatory",inappropriate language in bug comments?

Comment: I haven't personally seen much of that. Either people get gently reminded to stay on topic and behave themselves, or, I guess, LP is not a very fertile ground for trolling around, so people stay away, and troll facebook users.

Comment: Comments that are either spam, rude or inappropriate in nature, or completely off-topic are either just ignored, or marked as an invalid bug/comment and then tossed in the "forgotten" bin. Other than that it's usually left alone and is most often free of any major issues.

Comment: If a bug comment comes with a "sack the maintainer" the post should be removed imho. (as soon as possible)

Comment: @leoquant, if one of the answers has addressed your question would you mind marking it as accepted with its checkmark? It would also be great if you could vote up any helpful answers.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly not. Launchpad relies heavily on the community: bad bug reports are marked as invalid and simply forgotten.

For bad comments theres no "report button" but you can request removal on [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad) atleast for spam.

Comment: If a bug comment comes with a "sack the package maintainer", it should be removed imho.